# j2me multiple cookies

Tags: cookies, java-me

how to read http multiple responce headers with the same key name like set-cookie from j2me httpconnection? (looping through headers with getHeaderField(int i) also did not solve the problem). because of this problam i tried to rewite my own http client on a socket connection. but jsr-185 does not allow sockets to port 80, 8080 and 443. to use them application should be signed.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through headers with getHeaderField(int i) works for me in WTK emulator. IMHO, some devices can have this bug non-fixed: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4634244

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved like this. In the code below we are extracting "JSESSION" and "SOME_COOKIE", two cookies coming from a server that is using the same header "set-cookie".

```
String sessionID = "";
String someCookie = "";
String headerKey = "";
int indexField = 0;
while((headerKey = httpConnection.getHeaderFieldKey(indexField)) != null){
    String headerValue = httpConnection.getHeaderField(indexField);
    if(headerKey.equals("set-cookie")){
        //do something with the string
        if(headerValue.indexOf("JSESSION")>=0){//if "JSESSION" is present in the String
            sessionID = headerValue.substring(0, headerValue.indexOf(";"));
        }
        if(headerValue.indexOf("SOME_COOKIE")>=0){//if "SOME_COOKIE" is present in the String
            someCookie = headerValue.substring(0, headerValue.indexOf(";"));
        }
    }
    indexField++;
}
```